# Angular5: Why does nested FormArray FormControl disable when user begins to edit input?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5, angular-forms, formarray

I'm trying to create (what I thought) was a basic Scheduler component for a current project.

**EDIT:** I have found my own solution, and the answer is provided below. Bonus for any help solving the select all features, which I have shelved for the moment :)

tldr;

Question: **Why if I pass in a disabled row, enable it, and begin to edit, that row becomes disabled?** If I enable all rows OnInit, everything works as expected.

Editor StackBlitz: [Editor StackBlitz for Angular FormArray Table](https://stackblitz.com/edit/form-array)

App StackBlitz: [App Stackblitz for Angular FormArray table](https://form-array.stackblitz.io)

---

The goal is to allow a user to select and/or deselect specific days or time ranges within a form. If that column or row is selected, then their elements will toggle their 'active' state.

So, I toggle the Sunday column and Morning Row. Only the value pertaining to Sunday and Morning time ranges will be active.

I'm using *ngIf or hidden to hide elements from the user, so they cannot edit. If the form input is active, then they can view it an edit that field.

However, the issue comes when I initialize my form with rows that aren't active. So, I have the Morning Row active ngOnInit, and then the user can toggle rows once the state initializes.

When those disabled rows are enabled, and a user begins to edit, that row's **active state disables**. This is where I'm confused. I'm in the weeds and I can't seem to locate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

After debugging, I have solved my issues. For anyone who runs into a similar use case, my solution involved how I handled setting the active states on toggling the FormControl's values.

Previously I was toggling active values through Angular's getter function:

`[FormControl].value.[ActiveFormField] = !active_state`

Which wasn't updating the form's proper values.

Instead, I needed to set the values as such:

`[FormControl].value.[ActiveFormField].setValue(!active_state).`

By setting the value, the form was then properly updated, and my toggle states performed as expected.

---

I also cleaned up the nested `for-loops` I referenced; however, I still need to tackle select all and deselect all states.